# Eu não estou conseguindo enviar este formulário pro e-mail

Tags: php, html, email, envio-de-email

Não estou conseguindo enviar este formulário pro e-mail, eu segui um tutorial e não deu certo!

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-6 centro" method="POST">
        <img class="imagem" src="AMB.png">
        <form action="enviar.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nome">Nome Completo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cpf" onblur="TestaCPF(this)">CPF:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cpf">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="crm">CRM:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crm">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
            <button type="enviar" class="botao btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $para = 'email@email.org.br';
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $crm = $_POST['crm'];
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    $mensagem = '<strong>Nome: </strong>'.$nome;
    $mensagem .= '<br> <strong>CPF: </strong>'.$cpf;
    $mensagem .= '<br> <strong>CRM: </strong>'.$crm;
    $mensagem .= '<br> <strong>Email: </strong>'.$email;

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $para \r\n";

    $envio = mail($para, $nome, $cpf, $crm, $mensagem, $headers);

    echo "Formulário enviado com sucesso!";
?>
```

Comment: Existe alguma mensagem de erro? Se sim, adicione a pergunta por favor.  Você sabe que precisa ter o servidor [smtp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server) configurado corretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Você esqueceu algumas coisas básicas para o envio de email com PHP.

Quando você iniciou o formulário em `<form action="enviar.php">` você esqueceu o método que neste seu caso é `POST` ficando assim:

`<form action="enviar.php" method="post">`

Em cada input você precisa declarar `name` e não somente `id`. Por exemplo:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome">`

Deve ficar assim:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome">`

No seu PHP você precisa definir uma variável assunto, além de declarar dentro da mensagem as variáveis sem concatenar e usando aspas duplas, então você concatena apenas a próxima linha. A função `mail` não inclui todas as variáveis, pois elas vão dentro da varível `mensagem`.

Veja o código completo para entender melhor:

SEU HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-6 centro" method="POST">
        <img class="imagem" src="AMB.png">
        <form action="enviar.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nome">Nome Completo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cpf" onblur="TestaCPF(this)">CPF:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="crm">CRM:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crm" name="crm">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <button type="enviar" class="botao btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

SEU PHP:

```
<?php
    $para = 'email@email.org.br';
    $assunto = '(SEU ASSUNTO AQUI)';
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $crm = $_POST['crm'];
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);



    $mensagem = "<strong>Nome: </strong>$nome";
    $mensagem .= "<br> <strong>CPF: </strong>$cpf";
    $mensagem .= "<br> <strong>CRM: </strong>$crm";
    $mensagem .= "<br> <strong>Email: </strong>$email";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $para \r\n";

    $envio = mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);

    if($envio){
        echo "Formulário enviado com sucesso!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Erro";
    }

?>
```